# Lambda triggering on each SQS message despite batching size of 500 in lambda event source mapping

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I've set up a system that looks like this: lambda1 -> SQS -> lambda2

Lambda1 will send a number of messages to SQS (all within a few seconds). I've then set up and event source mapping between the SQS queue and lambda2 to have a `MaximumBatchingWindowInSeconds` of 180 seconds, and a `BatchSize` of 500. Given this setup, I'd only expect lambda2 to be triggered once (for up to 500 messages sent from lambda1 within 180 seconds). But the observed behavior (based on number of cloudwatch logs of lambda2), seems to be one trigger per message (SQSEvent passed to handler only contains one record). The `MaximumBatchingWindowInSeconds` of 180 seconds seems to be in effect though. Another detail is that lambda2's timeout is also 180 seconds. Any ideas on what could be happening here?

```
MyQueue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      QueueName: MyQueueName
      ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds: 10
      VisibilityTimeout: 180
```

```
LambdaFunctionEventSourceMapping:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping
    Properties:
      BatchSize: 500
      Enabled: true
      EventSourceArn: !GetAtt MyQueue.Arn
      FunctionName: !GetAtt MyLambdaFunction.Arn
      MaximumBatchingWindowInSeconds: 180
```

edit:

lambda1 sends messages to SQS using the sdk: `sqsClient.sendMessage(sendSQSMessageRequest);`

lambda2 receives SQSEvents through the handleRequest function:
`public Boolean handleRequest(final SQSEvent sqsEvent, final Context context)`

Comment: How are you reading from SQS?

Comment: Ah! Good point, @stdunbar -- If @Avi is calling the SQS API directly, then it will ignore the events passed to the Lambda function. The program should use the contents of `event` directly, without calling SQS. Hopefully the OP will show their code in the Question.

Comment: Made some edits to reflect this, lambda2 gets the contents of the SQSEvent directly as a parameter to the handleRequest method. So this doesn't seem to be calling SQS explicitly

Comment: Check invocation metric. From my experience `MaximumBatchingWindowInSeconds` does not mean "1 invocation per 180 seconds". Lambda will be invoked whenever it "thinks" it has good enough number of messages.

Comment: @Avi So you are saying that `SQSEvent` only contains one record? It should contain multiple records as shown on [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon SQS - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html).

Comment: @Marcin yea, I checked the invocation metric and it seems to reflect 5 invocations for 6 messages from SQS, so one invocation did contain 2 records it seems. When I tried with fewer messages though, it was 1 record per invocation

Comment: @John Rotenstein this seems consistent with the documentation, but I had expected all 6 records to be in one lambda invocation

Comment: You can tinker with `VisibilityTimeout`. I think it should be higher then `180 in your case, but I woudn't expect 1 invocation per 180 minutes.

Comment: please read this https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-adds-amazon-simple-queue-service-to-supported-event-sources/
where mentioned "the Lambda service will begin polling the SQS queue using five parallel long-polling connections" and seems some config does not comply with https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html

Comment: @Avi did you get this working? Any conclusion?

Comment: even using
      VisibilityTimeout: 360
      ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds: 20
and 
            BatchSize: 500
            MaximumBatchingWindowInSeconds: 60
I am getting separate invocations for events created a single second apart.  Seems like AWS prioritizes concurrency over batch-related config

Answer (score 0):

As per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html

Lambda passes all of the records in the batch to the function in a single call, as long as the total size of the events doesn't exceed the payload limit for synchronous invocation (6 MB).

Payload size can be one of the factors here.